# How to take screenshot on GT-19100 with ICS 4.0.4?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, screenshots

My Samsung Galaxy GT-19100 phone is stopped taking snapshot after my up-gradation from ICS 4.0.3 to ICS 4.0.4.
Volume (-) key and power button pressing together is not taking snapshot now.

Is this version of ICS doesn't have screenshot facility or something else is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by holding the power button + the home button simultaneously.